# How do you open a port on a cisco firewall?

Tags: cisco, port, cisco-pix

I'm sure this is simple but how do you open a port on a cisco firewall?

I want to use fixup to alias a port and then actually open the port.  But I don't know how to do it.  Thank you.

Comment: Which type of firewall? The process is different for a Pix or an ASA.

Comment: pix 515e is the model 6.1(2)

Comment: what do you mean by 'alias a port'?

Comment: I don't think fixup does what you think it does: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/pix/pix62/configuration/guide/fixup.html

Comment: ok...how can i just open port 1701?

Answer (score 1):

From the "<strike>priviledged</strike> configuration" command prompt:

```
static (inside_interface_name,outside_interface_name) (external ip address) (internal ip address)

access-list (access list name) ("permit" or "deny") (tcp or udp) any host (external_ip) eq (port number)

access-group (access list name) in interface (outside_interface)
```

Simple, right?

Good old Cisco.

The "Static" command tells the pix that the internal machine is attached to the external address, so that it will route traffic accordingly.

The "access-list" command tells the pix that you're creating a new access-list, you're allowing or denying "any" external machine to talk to your new external address on (port number) using tcp or udp packets.

The access-group command associates that access-list with an interface on the pix.

Here is a link to Cisco's [Pix Command Reference for Commands starting with A](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/pix/pix61/command/reference/a.html#wpxrefaccess-list). You can refer to that, if you need to. There is an example command under "access-group".

To wholly open a port for any machine you should do:

```
access-list open_port_whatever permit tcp any any eq (port number)
access-group open_port_whatever in interface (outside)
```

Comment: "Port 1701" implies L2TP. @johnny are you trying to pass PPTP through the firewall? If so, you'll have to allow GRE as well. http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/vpndevc/ps2030/products_configuration_example09186a0080094a5a.shtml

Comment: You need to be in config mode not priviledged mode (en <cr>;conf t<cr> instead of just en<cr>)

Comment: @gerald.  yes.  I opened the port and am trying to vpn from my xp machine.  What I don't understand is why it gives no hitcount for the ports 1701 or 1723 (I opened both).  It doesn't work but I'd be happy for the moment if I at least got a hitcount.